# Send Bigquery Data to rest endpoint

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to send data from BigQuery (about 500K rows) to a custom endpoint via post method, how can I do this?

These are my options:

A PHP process to read and send the data (I have already tried this one, but it is too slow and the max execution time pops up).
I was looking for Google Cloud Dataflow, but I don't know Java.
Running it into Google Cloud Function, but I don't know how to send data via post.

Do you know another option?

Comment: I can't help but feel that this may be too much data.  You didn't specify the nature of your receiving back-end application nor whether this is a one time transmission or recurring.  Can I suggest that you update your question with some more of the back story?

Comment: 500k rows via post is a bad idea. Most web servers will put a limit on POST data. Even if you can cross that limit you will have multiple other issues to deal with like timeouts and extra processing time. I would suggest saving the BigQuery output to a GCS bucket and then use the GCS object url to fetch the object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, 500k rows for a POST method is far too much data to be considered as an option.

Dataflow is a product oriented for pipelines development, intended to run several data transformations during its jobs. You can use [BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) (with python sample codes) but, If you just need to migrate the data to a certain machine/endpoint, creating a Dataflow job will add complexity to your task.

The suggested approach is to [export to a GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) and then [download the data from it](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects).

For instance, if the size of Data that you are trying to retrieve is less than 1GB, you can export to a GCS bucket from the Command Line Interface like: `bq extract --compression GZIP 'mydataset.mytable' gs://example-bucket/myfile.csv`. Otherwise, you will need to [export the data in more files using wildcard URI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files) defining your bucket destination as indicated ('`gs://my-bucket/file-name-*.json`').

And finally, using gsutil command `gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [SAVE_TO_LOCATION]` you will download the data from your bucket.

---

Note: you have more available ways to do that in the Cloud documentation links provided, including the BigQuery web UI.

Also, bear in mind that there are no charges for exporting data from BigQuery, but you do incur [charges for storing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing) the exported data in Cloud Storage. BigQuery exports are subject to the [limits on export jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files).